# Probability of default

Tags: probability

> **Problem.** Calculate the default probability $P(0<\tau<T)$ in the whole year, if the probability of default in the first half is equal to $0.1$ and in the second half it is equal to $0.1$ as well.

**My solution**.

\begin{align}
(1-0.1) \times (1-0.1) = 1-x
\end{align}

Solving for $x$, I get $x = 0.19$

I would like to ask if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: It depends on whether the two halves of the year are independent, including whether two defaults are possible in the year.

Comment: $$P(\textrm{Default in year})=P(\textrm{Second half default}|\textrm{First half no default})P(\textrm{First half no default})+P(\textrm{First half default})=0.1\cdot (1-0.1)+0.1=0.19$$

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that default in the first half of the year and default in the second half of the year are *disjoint events*.
If we interpret the expression "in the second half it [probability of default] is equal to 0.1 as well" at face value, then we should add 0.1 to 0.1 to get 0.2.
But it is possible that whoever wrote this question meant to say something more like "in the second half probability of default *given survival thus far* is equal to 0.1". In that case you and Snoop have the right answer. Personally I would make the more literal interpretation and answer 0.2.